# When im sending email with multiple attachments via smtplib in django. Only the last one can be opened

Tags: python, django, smtplib

Im creating django app which sends uploaded files to other users of the app. But only the last file which is attached to the email is readable, rest is corrupted and I don't know why.

Here is the code which I'm using to create email and add the attachments.
When it is only one file everything works perfectly.

```
            attachments         = request.FILES
            msg                 = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['Subject']      = subject
            msg['From']         = EMAIL_ADDRESS
            msg['To']           = ', '.join(recipients)

            msg.attach(MIMEText(body,"html"))
            
            if len(attachments.getlist('attachment')) != 0:
                for attachment in attachments.getlist('attachment'):

                    attach_file     = attachment.file
                    payload         = MIMEBase('application', attachment.content_type)
                    payload.set_payload(attach_file.read())
                    encoders.encode_base64(payload)
                    payload.add_header('content-disposition', 'attachment',filename=attachment.name)
                    msg.attach(payload)

            smtp_server         = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
            
            smtp_server.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, PASSWORD)
            smtp_server.sendmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, recipients, msg.as_string())
            smtp_server.quit()
```

I also tried django class EmailMessage, but the result was completely same.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works:

```
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

if len(attachments.getlist('attachment')) != 0:
   for attachment in attachments.getlist('attachment'):
       at = MIMEApplication(open(attachment, 'rb').read())
       at.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', 
                      filename=attachment.name)
       msg.attach(at)
```

Comment: I tried that but got this error.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `at = MIMEApplication(open(attachment, 'rb').read())
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile.` To be honest I dont know why it doesnt work. Im also uploading the files to azure storage and all files can be opened.

Comment: What about `at = MIMEApplication(open(attachment.file, 'rb').read())` ?

Comment: this also didnt work. But I found a solution. I used javascript to split the files so that each file has his own key in request.FILES and now I'm accesing them using the unique dict key and for some reason it works.